# Alternative to AWS' bucket.putObject() method in google-cloud/storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I would like to mimic the following AWS call using the google-cloud/storage package

```
const params = {
                Body: data,
                Key: key,
                ContentType: type
            };
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                bucket.putObject(params, function(error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: ', error);
                        reject(error);
                    }
                    resolve(data);                  
                });
            })
```

In the above call, if I pass some directory hierarchy in the Key param, the folder structure would be created and the file correctly placed.

For instance, if I pass the Key as 
**root/test_folder/input_file.json**
Then the file would be placed as
**S3:///root/test_folder/input_file.json**

I am unable to find a similar call in google-cloud/storage.
If I use the

```
<bucket>.upload()
```

method, I can place the file under a directory, but I can ONLY upload files!

```
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
        destination: 'abc/xyz',
```

If I use the

```
file.save()
```

method, I can put data into storage, but now I cannot put this under a specific directory!

```
await file.save(contents);
```

I need some way of putting content into a directory structure in google-storage and the directory structure may not exist.

Comment: I was able to do this with a combination of file.save() and file.move() but I dont think that's a very good way!

Comment: sorry I was wrong! this could be done only with the file.save() method!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I was wrong. This could simply be done with the file.save() method.
We just need to specify the path along with the filename .

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage();
    const myBucket = storage.bucket('bucket');

    const file = myBucket.file('xxx/yyy/my-file', { generation: 0 });
    const contents = 'This is the contents of the file.';

    file.save(contents, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        file.deleteResumableCache();
      }
    });
```

The above would store the file under

```
bucket/xxx/yyy
```